Avoid specifying produces and consumes for every route
I have an API that mostly produces and consumes an application/vnd mime type.
For some endpoints, I also want to handle different mime types. How do I avoid specifying the produces() and consumes() for every route?
For example: instead of:
    router.route("/user-roles/:email")
            .produces(VENDOR_MIME)
            .consumes(VENDOR_MIME)
            .method(PUT).handler(userRolesCrudHandler::replace);
    router.route("/user-roles/:email")
            .produces(VENDOR_MIME)
            .method(GET).handler(userRolesCrudHandler::read);
    router.route("/user-roles/:email")
            .produces(VENDOR_MIME)
            .method(DELETE).handler(userRolesCrudHandler::delete);
    router.route("/user-roles/:email")
            .produces("text/plain")
            .method(GET).handler(userRolesCrudHandler::readAsText);

Something like:
    router.
            .defaultProduces(VENDOR_MIME)
            .defaultConsumes(VENDOR_MIME)
    router.route("/user-roles/:email")
            .method(PUT).handler(userRolesCrudHandler::replace);
    router.route("/user-roles/:email")
            .method(GET).handler(userRolesCrudHandler::read);
    router.route("/user-roles/:email")
            .method(DELETE).handler(userRolesCrudHandler::delete);
    router.route("/user-roles/:email")
            .produces("text/plain")
            .method(GET).handler(userRolesCrudHandler::readAsText);


Didn't test it, but it's worth trying to create a subrouter and then mount it with produces/consumes methods: router.subRouter( userRolesRouter ).consumes( VENDOR_MIME ).produces( VENDOR_MIME )

How would I handle the exceptional case then?

exceptional in what regard?

The whole problem is all but one of the handlers produce VENDOR_MIME and one handler should produce text/plain. If I set produces(VENDOR_MIME) on sub router wouldn't that prevent me from returning text/plain

I think you should be able to overwrite the "default" type by calling produces()/consumes()

In my sample:
router.route("/api/*").produces("application/json");

This will apply config of produces to all sub path from /api
router.get("/api/v1/products").respond(this::getAllProducts);

You can override if want by
ctx.response().putHeader("Content-Type", "xxxx");

ctx = RoutingContext
